# How to write and read csv file each row python

Tags: python, export-to-csv, import-from-csv

I have this code which in python 2 :

```
import io 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
import pandas as pd
from Sastrawi.StopWordRemover.StopWordRemoverFactory import    StopWordRemoverFactory

factory = StopWordRemoverFactory()
stopwords = factory.get_stop_words()
stop_words = set(stopwords)

file1 = open('sample/wah.csv', 'rb')

line = file1.read()# Use this to read file content as a stream: 
words = line.split() 
for r in words: 
    if not r in stop_words: 
        appendFile = open('sample/wewe.csv','a') 
        appendFile.write(" "+r) 
        appendFile.close()
```

But the results are connected to each other, how to keep it separate each row or line ?

Comment: There should be a space between the words, right? Instead of `" "`, use `"\n"`…?!

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv as c

with open("C:\\Users\\Yogesh\\Desktop\\csvData.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = c.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    NumberOfLine = 0
    for i in csv_reader:
        if NumberOfLine == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(i)}')
            NumberOfLine += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{i[0]} , {i[1]} .')
            NumberOfLine += 1
    print(f'Number of lines  {NumberOfLine}')
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import io 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
import pandas as pd
from Sastrawi.StopWordRemover.StopWordRemoverFactory import    StopWordRemoverFactory

factory = StopWordRemoverFactory()
stopwords = factory.get_stop_words()
stop_words = set(stopwords)

file1 = open('sample/wah.csv', 'rb')

appendFile = open('sample/wewe.csv','a')

for line in file1.readline() # Process each line separately 
    words = line[:-1].split() 
    for r in words: 
        if not r in stop_words: 
             appendFile.write(r + " ")
    appendFile.write("\n") 
appendFile.close()
```

This will write all sentences line by line. Side Note: This won't create a csv file, if I am correctly inferring what you want. 
However, this code can be easily modified to do that.

Comment: There is a ':' missing after the for statement.  Also, a nice way would be to use a 'with' statement for handling appendFile.

Comment: Secondly, a slightly robust way would be to replace 'words = line[:-1].split()' with 'words = line.strip().split()'.